# How can I access a top level variable containing a dot in Ansible?

Tags: if-statement, ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to get a `when` condition to match a string value in a list of strings in Ansible. I'm defining my list variables in the `all` host inventory group. I call these list variables from many of play, playbooks and roles.

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    ubuntu_18.04_codenames:
      - 'bionic'
      - 'tara'
      - 'tessa'
      - 'tina'
      - 'tricia'
    ubuntu_20.04_codenames:
      - 'focal'
      - 'ulyana'
      - 'ulyssa'
      - 'uma'
      - 'una'
    ubuntu_22.04_codenames: 
      - 'jammy'
      - 'vera'
      - 'vanessa'
      - 'Victoria'
```

I define my task's when condition like this:

```yaml
- name: "Adding Docker 20.04 APT repository"
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
  when: 'ansible_lsb.codename in ubuntu_20.04_codenames'
```

I get the error:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_lsb.codename in ubuntu_22.04_codenames' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'integer'. String: {% if ansible_lsb.codename in ubuntu_22.04_codenames %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}. expected token 'end of statement block', got 'integer'

I'm using `ansible_lsb.codname` with my list variable `ubuntu_20.04_codenames`. I keep on getting syntax errors, no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take note first about [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names) as your current example would result into

```yaml
ERROR! Invalid variable name in vars specified for Play: 'ubuntu_18.04_codenames' is not a valid variable name
```

---

> ***... when condition to match a string value in a list of strings ...***

A minimal example playbook using [`contains` test – does the list contain this element](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/contains_test.html)

> *Checks the supplied element against the input list to see if it exists within it.*

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    ubuntu_18_04_codenames:
      - 'bionic'
      - 'tara'
      - 'tessa'
      - 'tina'
      - 'tricia'
    ubuntu_20_04_codenames:
      - 'focal'
      - 'ulyana'
      - 'ulyssa'
      - 'uma'
      - 'una'
    ubuntu_22_04_codenames:
      - 'jammy'
      - 'vera'
      - 'vanessa'
      - 'victoria'

    codename: focal

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "Yes. Contains ..."
    when: ubuntu_20_04_codenames is contains(codename)
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Yes. Contains ...
```

---

> ***I keep on getting syntax errors.***

If interested into reproducing the mentioned syntax error message, just change the condition to

```yaml
    when: ubuntu_20.04_codenames is contains(codename)
```

containing an invalid variable name. It will result into

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The conditional check '{{ ubuntu_20.04_codenames is contains(codename) }}' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '_codenames'. String: {{ ubuntu_20.04_codenames is contains(codename) }}
```

Comment: _your current example would result into_ > this is untrue as far as inventory variables are concerned. Would they be play or task variables, though, it would be correct.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, I see the point, you are correct. But then, for the conditional check, array notation and an other approach would be necessary as you already showed within your answer.

Comment: Doh! I should have known better than to put periods in variable names. And thanks for the hint on using the proper function to look up the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `.` has a meaning in Ansible — namely it helps access an attribute of a dictionary — using it in a top level variable is going to give you a little bit of trouble.

If you where in a second level attribute, i.e.:

```yaml
ubuntu:
  18.04_codenames:
    - bionic
```

You could just get away using the [*array notation*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#ansible-allows-dot-notation-and-array-notation-for-variables-which-notation-should-i-use):

```yaml
when: "ansible_lsb.codename in ubuntu['18.04_codenames']"
```

But, since you are at the top level of variables, you will have to resort to using the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html):

```yaml
when: "ansible_lsb.codename in lookup('vars', 'ubuntu_18.04_codenames')"
```

---

Given the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    ubuntu_18.04_codenames:
      - bionic
```

And the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: lookup('vars', 'ubuntu_18.04_codenames')
  when: "'bionic' in lookup('vars', 'ubuntu_18.04_codenames')"
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  lookup('vars', 'ubuntu_18.04_codenames'):
  - bionic
```